# update Vuex store from main proccess electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, electron

How I can update a vuex store by commiting things from main proccess? for example:

In main thread:

```
import store from ../store

ipc.on('someevent', (event, args) => {
    // do stuff with args
store.commit('update-things')
})
```

and in the renderer update components with these modifications.

Edit:
Real code:

main.js

```
import store from '../store'
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
const WebTorrent = require('webtorrent')
const client = new WebTorrent()

ipcMain.on('addMagnet', (event, arg) => {
   client.add(arg, function (torrent) {
   var files = []
    torrent.files.forEach(function (file) {

    files.push({
        title: file.name,
        torrent: torrent.infoHash,
        index: torrent.files.indexOf(file),
        duration: '--:--'
    })
   })
  store.commit('addSongs', files)
})
```

and store mutation is like:

```
addSongs (state, newSongs) {
    newSongs.forEach(function (song) {
      state.songs.push(song)
    })
}
```

store is in diferent directory that main.js if it's helps.

the component that uses store is:

```
**by this component:

     <template>
      <div id="playlist">
        <div
          is="song"
          v-for="song in songs"
          v-bind:title="song.title"
          v-bind:torrent="song.torrent"
          v-bind:index="song.index">
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import Song from './SongList/Song'

export default {
  name: 'playlist',
  components: { Song },
  computed: {
    songs () {
      return this.$store.getters.songs
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That all looks correct, what's not working as expected?

Comment: when I commit the update-things html doesnt changed,I can update real code if it helps.

Comment: Yeah you'll need to show the relevant code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153291/discussion-between-thanksd-and-rafaelleru).

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. Basically you're dealing with two separate stores because the main process is different than the renderer.

Comment: And whats the better way to fix it @Bert

Comment: If the files *have* to be collected in the main process, I expect what you will have to do is send the `files` object back to the renderer using IPC in order to commit to the store.

Comment: Yes but I will need to manage the ipcmessage in a vue object or I can simply create a file ipc.js and do all the stuff in that file? @Bert

Comment: The store is going to live in your renderer process. You need to send the things that need to be committed to the store to the renderer. In the event handler in the renderer that receives the files you can commit to the store.

Comment: can you answer the question please @Bert

Comment: I don't have the time right now to mock out an electron based example for you sorry. Just keep in mind that you're dealing with two different processes and the store can only live in one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but for future searchers, you can use `vuex-electron` to dispatch to the store from the main thread.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-electron